# How to exclude Google Photos from Google Drive searches?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos, google-drive-search

When I perform searches I frequently receive a lot of results of photos in my searches.  I would like to exclude these from my searches, how can I do this?

Is there a cheatsheet of sorts that show the various search options that exist for Google Drive?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this questions has become obsolete. The integration between Google  Photos and Google Drive was retired. Ref. [Changing how Google Drive and Google Photos work together](https://blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Add the following to your searches in Google Drive to exclude photos and other images:

`-type:image`

## Remarks

The reference include the "cheat sheet" of Google Drive search operators. It appears in the the section "More search options > Advanced search in Drive".

## References

- [Search for your files - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en)

Answer (score -2):

This does not work for me - adding "-type:image" displays only images, like it would do without the modifier.

Adding "-jpg" and "-png" to the search string works for me.

Comment: _What_ doesn't work for you? If you're referring to another answer, please link to it so that readers have context. Remember: Answers can be sorted a number of different ways; this isn't a threaded discussion forum.

Comment: I know that. That's why I've written what doesn't work for me - and what works for me as an answer.

Comment: What does "This" refer to? That's what I'm on about.